# Is there a way to send acknowledgement response in AWS Lambda functions

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, slack, slack-api

I am trying to handle a modal submission in slack, but there are some database operations in between which are taking a few seconds of time, due to this delay, I am getting: `We had some trouble connecting error when submitting slack dialog (Slack API)`

I know in node.js we can do something like this:

```
app.post('/', async (req, res){
   res.status(200).send({text: 'Acknowledgement received !'});
   
   // handle other task
   return res.json({done: 'Yipee !'})
})
```

But in AWS Lambda function, I have no idea how will I handle this acknowledgement response in 3 sec.

```
module.exports.events = async (event, context, callback) => {
  ??? -> How to handle acknowledgement here, it must be handled at top.

  // handle task
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({text: 'Done !'})
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to get notified for a successfull invocation and then have the lambda keep doing its own thing you can invoke lambda asynchronously by setting the InvocationType parameter to Event. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html#API_Invoke_RequestSyntax

Answer (score 0):

Slack's API can be difficult to handle with a serverless architecture, as most serverless implementations like the response to be the last thing they do, rather than the first. One approach would be to wrap any required behaviour inside a promise, and only resolve that promise once you have handled the task. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async) for an example of this.